# How to use discord.on_reaction_add() on messages sent before bot started

Tags: discord, discord.py

My Discord bot can only react to reactions added to messages sent after the bot started.
It won't react if I add a reaction to an old message.
How can I make it react to every reaction added, no matter when the message was sent?

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print(str(reaction.emoji), str(user))
```

When I add a reaction to a message sent after the Bot started, it works just fine.

```
User#1234 added a reaction to a message
```

When I add a reaction to a message sent before the Bot started, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`on_reaction_add` will only work for messages stored in the bots internal cache, which will only include those sent after it started.  To process reactions from other messages, you must use the [`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) event:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
    print(str(payload.emoji), str(user))
```